# Who vs whom usage

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, who-whom

> 1. I have a friend **whom** I met last year, started a new business, was not interested in it.
> 2. I have a friend **who** I met last year, started a new business, was not interested in it.

My grammar book is saying sentence2 is correct as “who” becomes subject of started a business, was not interested in it.

But I feel that sentence1 is correct, as whom becomes object of I met last year.

Which is correct?

Comment: The sentence is very unclear to me (which person started the business, and which wasn't interested?) _I have a friend whom I met last year, who started a new business but wasn't interested in it_ would make more sense.

Comment: The main part of the sentence is ungrammatical (as well as ambiguous), regardless of the use of use of **who** or **whom**. So, neither of the two examples sentences are correct as they stand. If they come from a grammar book, it's not a very good grammar book, and I wouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence contains the following clauses :

Main clause : I have a friend.

Subordinate clause (1) : who/whom I met

Subordinate clause (2) : who started a new business

Subordinate clause (3) : who was not interested in it.

The relative pronoun **who** is common in these subordinate clauses. So, if you introduce the 1st subordinate clause with **who**, you can omit it in other two clauses :

> I have a friend **who** I met last year,  (who) started a new business, and (who) was not interested in it.

[The objective form of **"who"** is **whom** or **who**].

If you introduce the first subordinate clause with **'whom'**, you have to introduce the other clauses with **'who'**.

> I have a friend **whom** I met last year, **who** started a new business and **who** was not interested in it.

You can omit the 2nd *who* in this sentence.